# change parameter with {{index+1}} angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-ng-repeat

I try to display highcharts with `ng-repeat`
**here is html:**

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="key in keys">
    <td>
        <div style="width: 140px; height: 37px; margin: 0 auto" class="hc-pie" items="values{{index+1}}"></div>
    </td>
    <td>{{key.perfomance}}</td>
    <td>{{key.current}}</td>
    <td>{{key.previous}}</td>
    <td>{{key.variance}}</td>
</tr>
```

**and my values grom controller:**

```
 $scope.values1=[
    ['value', 42.4],
    ['value', 33.2],
    ['value', 34.5],
    ['value', 39.7],
    ['value', 52.6],
    ['value', 75.5],
    ['value', 57.4],
    ['value', 60.4],
    ['value', 47.6],
    ['value', 39.1],
    ['value', 46.8],
    ['value', 51.1]
  ];
  $scope.values2=[
    ['value', 32.4],
    ['value', 13.2],
    ['value', 84.5],
    ['value', 19.7],
    ['value', 22.6],
    ['value', 65.5],
    ['value', 77.4],
    ['value', 90.4],
    ['value', 17.6],
    ['value', 59.1],
    ['value', 76.8],
    ['value', 21.1]
  ];
```

**and another data:**

```
  $scope.keys=[
  {perfomance:'ccc',
    current:'a',
    previous:'b',
    variance:'c',
    plus:false,
  },{perfomance:'bbb',
      current:'a',
      previous:'b',
      variance:'c',
      plus:true,
  },{perfomance:'aaa',
    current:'a',
    previous:'b',
    variance:'c',
    plus:false,
  }
      ];
```

**also my directive:**

```
.directive('hcPie', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      items: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      console.log(2);

    },
    template: '<div id="container" style="margin: 0 auto">not working</div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
          renderTo: element[0],
          type: 'column',
          backgroundColor: null
        },
        title: {
          text: null
        },
        subtitle: {
          text: null
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: [
            'Jan',
            'Feb',
            'Mar',
            'Apr',
            'May',
            'Jun',
            'Jul',
            'Aug',
            'Sep',
            'Oct',
            'Nov',
            'Dec'
          ],
          labels: {
            enabled: false
          },
          gridLineWidth: 0,
          minorGridLineWidth: 0,
          lineColor: 'transparent',
          tickLength: 0
        },
        yAxis: {
          gridLineWidth: 0,
          minorGridLineWidth: 0,
          lineColor: 'transparent',
          min: 0,
          title: {
            text: null
          },
          labels: {
            enabled: false
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
          column: {
            pointPadding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0,
            states: {
              hover: {
                color: '#FFFFFF'
              }
            }
          }
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'Value',
          color: '#EC5B00',
          data: scope.items

        }]
      });
      scope.$watch("items", function (newValue) {
        chart.series[0].setData(newValue, true);
      }, true);
    }
  }
});
```

I tried to change value with  `items="values{{index+1}}"` but it displays the same in html insted of `items="values1"`
to display another highchart
but it dosn't change
what I missed?

Comment: I dont know what is wrong in that but you should use '$index' instead of index

Comment: @saikumar I used but it doesn't change in html it displays like  `<div style="width: 140px; height: 37px; margin: 0 auto" class="hc-pie" items="values1{{$index+1}}"></div>`

Comment: This problem description is really lacking in details

Comment: Does your console give any errors?

Comment: @Mikey it give syntax error, but I can't understand where is it

Answer (score 0):

You should not use curly braces with two-way binding, because it makes angular expression invalid.

In your case you just want to use bracket notation in order to reference object properties by dynamic key (also note, that it's `$index` not `index`):

```
<div class="hc-pie" items="this['values' + ($index + 1)]" style="width: 140px; height: 37px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think this will evaluate correctly. You still would need the curly braces to evaluate.

Comment: Thank's but output displays: `items="'values' + (index + 1)"` insted of `items="values1"`, as I trying to do

Comment: Oh, sure, I misunderstood what you need. In this case you just want to use bracket notation in order to reference object properties by dynamic key.

Comment: @dfsq I trying to change `items="values"` with `{{$index}}` to `items="values1"`, `items="values2"`, `items="valuesn"`

Comment: @FrontEndist So what I posted should do it.

Comment: @dfsq, no, I just commented, is it forbidden?

Comment: @FrontEndist You can't use {{ }} in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Restructure your data:

```
$scope.values[1]=[
      {'value': 42.4},
      {'value': 33.2}
     ]
$scope.values[2]=[
      {'value': 32.4},
      {'value': 13.2}
     ]
```

Then in your HTML use:

```
<div class="hc-pie" items="values[index+1]"></div>
```